# Hbase time-series data format: Using composite key vs. Using versioning with timestamp

Tags: sorting, key, hbase, composite-key

I like to store the log of byte counters for 10 Million LAN devices.
Each device reports byte counter value every 15 minutes (96 samples/day), and each data sample has 500 columns. Each device is identified by its device serial `dev_sn`.

At the end of day, I will process the data (compute the total byte per device) for all the devices and store them into HIVE data format.

The raw data would be like this:(ex. Device `sn1`,`sn2`,and `sn3` report values at `t1`,`t2`,and `t3`)

[image]

Method 1: Use both `dev_sn` and `timestamp` as the composite `row-key`.
[image]

Method 2: Use `dev_sn` as the `row-key` and store each data as the version update of the existing values.

[image]

To find the total bytes,

- Method 1: Search by `sn1` for composite key and sort by time and process the data
- Method 2: Search by `sn1` and pull all the versions and process the data

I think Method 2 is a better solution as it will create less number of row-keys, but not sure if that is really the better approach. Some advice would really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is subjective, but I always opt for a composite row key over versioning, for the following reasons:

1. You can store unlimited "versions" per device. With versioning, this property is limited (as set in configuration).
2. It's much easier to retrieve entries from specific timestamps/time ranges with an HBase command. Prefix scans are much easier to work with than the version API.
3. There's no reason for you to want to reduce the number of row keys - HBase is designed specifically to store huge numbers of row keys.
4. What if you need to delete last Tuesday's data? With versioning that's difficult, with composite keys it's a small piece of code.

As an aside, be sure to pre-split your region servers so that the `dev_sn` values distribute evenly.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am getting to have the impression that handling timestamp is more complicated than handling composite row-keys. So  composite key seems the better approach as you have suggested.